# Custom serialize fields do not save values after switching to game mode

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, serialization

I have custom serialise fields that are displayed in the inspector, but when I add values to them and switch to game mode, the field values are cancelled. I know, I can just inherit my modules from MonoBehaviour but i don't want in order to overload class not important function and properies to initialise the fields.

```
using System;
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEngine;
using Helpers.Utils;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace GameEnviroment.Assembling
{
    public class GAssembly : MonoBehaviour
    {
        private readonly static List<FieldInfo> GSerializedModulesFields = new();

        public static LabModule LabModule { get; private set; } = new LabModule();
        public static EvalModule EvalModule { get; private set; } = new EvalModule();
        public static AdsModule AdsModule { get; private set; } = new AdsModule();

        private readonly static List<GModule> Modules = new()
        {
            LabModule, EvalModule, AdsModule
        };

        private void Awake()
        {
            DontDestroyOnLoad(this);
        }

#if UNITY_EDITOR
        [CustomEditor(typeof(GAssembly))]
        internal sealed class GAssemblyInspector : Editor
        {
            public override void OnInspectorGUI()
            {
                DrawDefaultInspector();
                
                serializedObject.Update();

                if (Modules == null) return;

                for (int i = 0; i < GSerializedModulesFields.Count; i++)
                {
                    if (i == 0 || GSerializedModulesFields[i].DeclaringType.Name != GSerializedModulesFields[i - 1].DeclaringType.Name)
                    {
                        GUILayout.Space(10f);
                        GUILayout.Label(GUtility.HandleFieldName(GSerializedModulesFields[i].DeclaringType.Name, '-', false, '_'), EditorStyles.boldLabel);
                        GUILayout.Space(5f);
                    }

                    if (GUtility.GetFinalBaseType(GSerializedModulesFields[i].FieldType) == typeof(UnityEngine.Object))
                    {
                        GModule module = Modules.Find(m => m.GetType() == GSerializedModulesFields[i].DeclaringType);

                        GSerializedModulesFields[i].SetValue(module, EditorGUILayout.ObjectField(
                            label: GUtility.HandleFieldName(GSerializedModulesFields[i].Name, exclude: '_'),
                            obj: GSerializedModulesFields[i].GetValue(module) as UnityEngine.Object,
                            objType: GSerializedModulesFields[i].FieldType,
                            allowSceneObjects: true));
                    }
                    
                    else if (GSerializedModulesFields[i].FieldType == typeof(float))
                    {
                        GModule module = Modules.Find(m => m.GetType() == GSerializedModulesFields[i].DeclaringType);

                        GSerializedModulesFields[i].SetValue(module, EditorGUILayout.FloatField(
                            label: GUtility.HandleFieldName(GSerializedModulesFields[i].Name, exclude: '_'),
                            value: Convert.ToSingle(GSerializedModulesFields[i].GetValue(module))));
                    }

                    // else if (GSerializedModulesFields[i].FieldType == typeof(string))
                    // {
                    // ...
                    // }
                    //
                    // else if ....
                }

                serializedObject.ApplyModifiedProperties();
            }
        }
#endif
        [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Field, Inherited = false, AllowMultiple = true)]
        internal sealed class SerializeFieldAttribute : Attribute
        {
            public SerializeFieldAttribute() { }

            public static void InitializeFields(Type targetObject)
            {
                IEnumerable<FieldInfo> fields =     GUtility.GetFieldsWithAttribute<SerializeFieldAttribute>(targetObject);
                foreach (FieldInfo field in fields)
                {
                    GSerializedModulesFields.Add(field);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The field to which i apply GAssembly.SerializeField attribute are showing in the inspector and even i can set value for them, but when i start play mode all field values disappears

I think that on start of the game all fields are serialize and my fields not serialize and not save in Unity. I try give different attributes (Serializable for modules class, UnityEngine.SerializeField for fields) but it doesn't work.

Maybe I need create own serialization system? Or maybe I can use Unity serialization system for?

Comment: Because static fields are not serializable, using a prefab, a global game object or a scriptable object instead.

Comment: `FieldInfo` is not serializable .. further `SerializeField` is a Unity built-in type .. you should use a different name

Comment: Even further in general static or read-only fields and properties etc are also not serialized .. maybe your Inspector fills them now .. but when loading this again without happening to have your inspector open those fields  properties are never filled ... Which is exactly what happens on entering Playmode since it performs a domain reload

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? In general you probably should avoid using reflection at all

Comment: @derHugo I just need each module to be able to initialise fields through the inspector, but without inheriting from MonoBehaviour. The modules should be static structures that process the data they receive and provide the data directly to others, and should not touch the methods and properties of MonoBehaviour. I am very confused by the fact that it is necessary to inherit from MonoBehaviour even when you just need to initialise fields, so I want to create my own data transfer system.

Comment: @derHugo I tried using a singleton without readonly and static fields, but to no avail. I understand that FieldInfo is not serialised, and if I got some data through a custom inspector, I need to save it through my own serialisation system (BinaryFormatter, JSON, etc.), but that's not what I want. 

Maybe there are other ways to solve this problem (besides duplicating the fields in another Mono script and initialising them with Awake)?

Comment: Sounds like you want `ScriptableObject` instead

Comment: https://gamedevbeginner.com/scriptable-objects-in-unity/

Comment: In most cases you want to avoid `static`s .. most of the time it is just laziness of not doing proper reference management

Comment: @derHugo modules should be available in all scenes

Comment: @derHugo oh! ScriptableObject is actually what I need! Thank you very much! ❤